# Swift: NSCollectionViewItem not showing in NSViewController

Tags: swift, cocoa, nscollectionview

I am building an app with `NSCollectionView` and behaviour of `NSCollectionView` is so strange, sometimes it makes cell's visible and sometimes are not.

```
@IBOutlet weak var resourceCollectionView: NSCollectionView!

private func prepareCollectionView() {
    let flowLayoutForEvent = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
flowLayoutForEvent.scrollDirection = .vertical
flowLayoutForEvent.minimumInteritemSpacing = 100
       
resourceCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayoutForEvent
       
resourceCollectionView.delegate = self
resourceCollectionView.dataSource = self
resourceCollectionView.isSelectable = true
       
       
resourceCollectionView.backgroundColors = [.clear]
resourceCollectionView.register(SimpleCell.self, forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "SimpleCell"))
}
```

Then applied the function

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         prepareCollectionView()
    }
```

Here is extension function for `NSCollectionView`

```
extension DashboardController : NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, NSCollectionViewDataSource {
  
  // 1
  public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: NSCollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }
  
  // 2
  public func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }
  
  // 3
  public func collectionView(_ itemForRepresentedObjectAtcollectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {    
    let cell = resourceCollectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "SimpleCell"), for: indexPath) as! SimpleCell

   
     return cell

  }
    
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {
        print("selected item > ",  indexPaths )
    }
    
    
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSSize {
        return NSSize(width: 10 , height:10)
    }
    
  
}
```

Here is programmatically cell for `NSCollectionView`

```
class SimpleCell: NSCollectionViewItem {

private var containerView: NSView!

private var containBox: NSBox = {
    var box = NSBox()
    box.boxType = .custom
    box.fillColor = NSColor.purple
    box.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return box
}()


override func loadView() {
    containerView = NSView()
    self.view = containerView
    containerView.bounds = self.view.bounds


    containerView.addSubview(containBox)
    containBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    containBox.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    containBox.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    containBox.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
}


}
```

resourceCollectionView not showing the cells and there is a strange behaviour such as when I add a line `resourceCollectionView.reloadData()` it shows up and then hides all cells automatically.

What is the missing points for the situation?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I've solved my problem, when I show another `NSViewController` I used

```
self.view = anotherViewController.view
```

then no functions of NSCollectionView is triggered.

Then I changed it to

```
self.view.window?.contentViewController = anotherViewController
```

Then it worked.

Comment: `public func collectionView(_ itemForRepresentedObjectAtcollectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem` looks like it's pasted twice.

Comment: Hey @Willeke, I solved my problem but I would like to learn to what is going on in background mechanism? I edited my problem with how I solved it, can you answer if you know the answer for that why it did not worked when I changed `view` property and why it worked directly changed `NSViewController` ?

Comment: Is `anotherViewController` a local variable and is this view controller released when it goes out of scope?

Comment: @elia Instead of editing the answer into the question, please add it as an answer. There's nothing wrong with answering your own question, and then you can accept the answer so that others realize that you no longer need help.

Comment: its created in `viewDidLoad` block, not a local variable. For testing purpose I created the variable in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: hey @Caleb, thanks for commenting, I will do it but I would like to learn what is going on background ? I would like to learn it because it took me 2 hours to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem, when I show another NSViewController I used

```
self.view = anotherViewController.view
```

then no functions of NSCollectionView is triggered.

Then I changed it to

```
self.view.window?.contentViewController = anotherViewController
```

It solved my problem.